# Writing a DataGridView to a CSV-file returns blank line sometime

Tags: c#, csv, datagridview

I have a code that export my DatagridCells to **`.CSV`**, but I'm having a problem reading it through a <kbd>MetaTrader Terminal</kbd> program as the `.CSV` files were having Blank Space in the 1st line and after that, the `.CSV` files are either blank some moments and back to normal.

Is it something to do with my code or with `DataGridView`s?

```
public void writeCSV2(DataGridView gridIn, string outputFil)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer) + "\\Useful\\"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer) + "\\Useful\\");
        }
        if (gridIn.RowCount > 0)
        {   
            string value = "";
            DataGridViewRow dr = new DataGridViewRow();//
             //write DataGridView rows to csv
            for (int j = 0; j <= gridIn.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                dr = gridIn.Rows[j];
                var oFile = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer)+"\\Useful\\" +dr.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + ".csv";
                using (StreamWriter swOut = new StreamWriter(oFile))
                {

                    if (j > 0)
                    {
                        swOut.WriteLine();
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i <= gridIn.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        if (i > 0)
                        {
                            swOut.Write(", ");
                        }

                        value = dr.Cells[i].Value.ToString();

                        //replace comma's with spaces
                        value = value.Replace(',', ' ');
                        //replace embedded newlines with spaces
                        value = value.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
                        swOut.Write(value);

                    }
                    swOut.Close();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for help and opinion on this

Comment: You're creating for each `DataGridViewRow` a new csv file. Are you doing this on purpose?

Comment: Yes, to make all the Rows have csv files per its name...

Comment: The blank line is because of the if statement. `if(j > 0) { swOut.WriteLine(); }`. This just writes a blank line on the top for every file except the first file.

Comment: Thanks for that, its been confusing me all the way.
How do i make the DataGridView Cells update the CSV file every time(ms)

Comment: What do you mean with "update the CSV file every time"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blank line you're talking about will be on the top of every file except your first csv file. Remove

```
if (j > 0)
{
    swOut.WriteLine();
}
```

from your code and there won't be any blank lines on top of your files anymore.

To answer your second question: Use a `Timer`. Just drag it from your toolbox or add it programmatically:

```
Timer timer1 = new Timer();
timer1.Interval = 1; // interval property is in milliseconds. use 1 for 1ms, 1000 for 1 second etc.
timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
timer1.Enabled = true;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // disable timer to avoid getting triggered while executing method
    timer1.Enabled = false;

    // run your method
    writeCSV2(gridIn, outputFil);

    // reenable the timer
    timer1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: I removed that and its now working fine without blankline, but i need this writetocsv() function to run every millisecond without stopping...

Comment: You could add a timer. I'll edit my answer, wait a minute please.

Comment: Ok, I'll be expecting that.. Thanks.

Comment: Seen. It works well as i have a timer_tick in my code, so i just added this function to it and it is working fine now..
Thanks